# Why did Merlin's "voicemail" tell the heroes they need Nimue to defeat the Dark One?

Tags: once-upon-a-time, arthurian

In the Once Upon a Time episode [*The Bear and the Bow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bear_and_the_Bow), our heroes use the magic mushroom to summon Merlin. But instead of Merlin, they get Merlin's "voicemail," that tells our heroes that the only way the Dark One can be defeated is by Nimue. Why would Merlin say such a thing? Especially since we find out in the next episode, [*Nimue*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimue_(Once_Upon_a_Time)), that Nimue

> was Merlin's girlfriend that became the very first Dark One.

Comment: Merlin is talking about the one he knew as Nimue, not the person whom he doesn't consider to be 'Nimue', I guess

Comment: OUAT has not been making sense since the Camelot reveal

Comment: @BCLC - Only since then? ;)

Comment: @Adamant if but not probably not only if :P

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer this without spoiling the current episodes.

> Nimue is the very first dark one. As a result, she is the only one who can truly defeat the darkness within each new dark one. In order for the darkness to be defeated, Nimue needs to either be destroyed, or overpowered so that her darkness cannot snuff out the light. Either way, it's basically up to Nimue to stop it.

Comment: I watched the episodes and I did not see what you are replying here  :)