# Once Upon a Time Wish Realm: Why does one want a dark curse still?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

**2021 Edit**: I didn't continue OUAT much afterwards, but I bet there's nothing to explain this just like the millions of plotholes this show had starting after Frozen.

---

**Question**: Does it make sense that Wish Realm Rumple wanted the dark curse to have been casted? It's not like he abandoned Baelfire in this universe. I mean, Henry exists, and they have that portrait of Baelfire soooo...?

**Note**: My asking is based on the middle of season 6 winter finale. I have a feeling the episode [will not explain](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112368/did-regina-rape-graham) this [inconsistency](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108267/).

Comment: Both verses are the same up to the casting of the curse, so baelfire is gone but some how returns. Rumble's prison was moved and he seems to have been forgotten about so doesn't know his son returned.

Comment: @Bosc would make sense if true I guess, but how do you know?

Comment: I'll need to watch again but isn't it said that Emma is only the savoir because of the curse and the wish stopped the curse. Wish Rumple  calls the queen out about failing to cast it meaning everything should be the same up to that point.

Comment: @Bosc yes that's the case and you already have potential answer