# Wishverse Henry is still named Henry

Tags: once-upon-a-time

**Note**: My asking is based on the middle of season 6 winter finale. I have a feeling the episode [will not explain](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112368/did-regina-rape-graham) this [inconsistency](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108267/).

Why is the wishverse son of Emma still named Henry? He was named such originally because of Regina's dad while under custody of Regina. Since Regina presumably never gains custody of Henry, why is Henry still so-named?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Once Upon A Time* screenwriter [Adam Horowitz answered this on Twitter](https://twitter.com/FordMiss/status/806291628759646212?s=20) in response to the question:

> Why Henry was called Henry if that was the name Regina gave after HER father? 
> [the "history" the wish created was different than the one in real EF.](https://twitter.com/AdamHorowitzLA/status/806293321840590848?s=20) 
> [so it doenst necessary have to make sense bc its a twisted version, thanks again](https://twitter.com/FordMiss/status/806293935563882496?s=20) 
> [it makes sense within the history created in that realm. There are rules and such, some of which we explore more](https://twitter.com/AdamHorowitzLA/status/806294120440348672?s=20)

Here’s my interpretation: OOU, it complicates their logistics, branding, etc. if they name him something different from what the character has been known as; “Wishverse Henry” is more meaningful and simpler than “Bob (aka Wishverse Henry).” Also they may not have wanted to get that deep into this alternate universe narrative. IU: Even though Henry had meaning in the normal universe, the Wishverse played out completely differently, yet somehow Henry is also named that for something meaningful in the Wishverse too — you just don’t know what it is & may never know.